# How to launch MobileIron Docs@Work app from another iOS app?

Tags: ios, mobileiron

I am trying to figure out the URL name for MobileIron Docsb@Work in order to launch it from another app. For most apps you can type in "appname://" and it will prompt to launch the application

Answer (score 0):

MobileIron iOS Docs@Work does not expose any URLScheme for third party apps to launch it.